# Add different shade colors for trend and forecast , with text on the region

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"y" : np.random.rand(20)})
ax = df.iloc[:15,:].plot(ls="-", color="b")
ax2 = ax.twinx()           #Create a twin Axes sharing the xaxis

df.iloc[15:,:].plot(ls="--", color="r", ax=ax)
plt.axhline(y=0.5,linestyle="--",animated=True,label="False Alaram")

plt.show()
```

So, first 15 are trend and last 5 are predictions.

I want different colors for trend and pred in background.
Also, how can i add text "Historic" and "Forecast" on graph.

[image: Reference picture here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"y" : np.random.rand(20)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

df.iloc[:15,:].plot(ls="-", color="b", ax=ax)
plt.fill_between(df.iloc[:15].index.tolist(), df.iloc[:15].y.tolist(), alpha=.25, color='b')

df.iloc[15:,:].plot(ls="--", color="r", ax=ax)
plt.axhline(y=0.5,linestyle="--", animated=True, label="False Alaram")
plt.fill_between(df.iloc[15:].index.tolist(), df.iloc[15:].y.tolist(), alpha=.25, color='r')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works well, thanks. One more thing, how can i add "False Alarm" text on the horizontal line i.e y=0.5 like in the reference image shown.

Comment: I would use [`plt.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) for that, something like `plt.annotate('False Alaram', (0, 0.55))`. Also, remove the line `plt.legend()` I've added.